# How to do a safe join pathname in ruby?

Tags: ruby

My Rails development environment is Windows-based, and my production environment is Linux-based.

It's possible that VirtualHost will be used. Assume that one filename needs to be referenced in the `/public` folder with `File.open('/tmp/abc.txt', 'r')`.

—but in Windows it should be `C:\tmp\abc.txt`. How can I do a correct path join to handle the two different environments?

```
prefix_tmp_path = '/tmp/'
filename = "/#{rand(10)}.txt"

fullname = prefix_tmp_path + filename # /tmp//1.txt <- but I don't want a double //
```

And when `prefix_tmp_path = "C:\tmp\"` I get `C:\tmp\/1.txt`

What is the correct way to handle both cases?

Answer (score 398, accepted):

I recommend using File.join

```
>> File.join("path", "to", "join")
=> "path/to/join"
```

Answer (score 59):

One thing to note. Ruby uses a "/" for file separator on all platforms, including Windows, so you don't actually need use different code for joining things together on different platforms. "C:/tmp/1.text" should work fine.

[File.join()](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html#M002568) is your friend for joining paths together.

```
prefix_tmp_path = 'C:/tmp'
filename = "#{rand(10)}.txt"
fullname = File.join(prefix_tmp_path, filename) # e.g., C:/tmp/3.txt
```